# How to add label to Pull Request via Github API?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkinsfile

According to GitHub API user can add label to an issue using [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#add-labels-to-an-issue) POST request.

I tried using this request but with PR number instead to automatically set label on PR. Here is the function I wrote:

```
def setLabel (String repository, List labels) {
    try {
        def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'POST',
                    url: "https:[Repo_URL]/${repository}/issues/${CHANGE_ID}/labels",
                    authentication: 'ors_git_service_account',
                    requestBody: """{
                        "labels": labels
                    }"""
    } catch (e) {
        wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
            echo "\u001B[31magdSlack.setLabels: '" + e.toString() + "'\u001B[0m"
        }
        throw e
    }
}
```

And the response I get is `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

So I get that this request can't be used to labeling PRs.

My question: **Is there other method which could be triggered from Jenkinsfile, to add or change PR label?**

Closest thing to the question I asked was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744069/create-comment-on-pull-request). Commenting API works on issues and PRs but that's not a case for labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by changing the way `labels` argument is passed into `requestBody`.

Turns out the list representation while interpolated into string is missing quotation marks around each list element.

```
def setLabels (String repository, List label) {
    try {
        String labelsAsString = "[\"${label.join('", "')}\"]"
        def response = httpRequest httpMode: 'POST',
                        url: "[REPO_URL]/${repository}/issues/${CHANGE_ID}/labels",
                        authentication: 'ors_git_service_account',
                        requestBody: """{
                            "labels": ${labelsAsString}
                        }"""
    } catch (e) {
        wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm']) {
            echo "\u001B[31magdSlack.setLabels: '" + e.toString() + "'\u001B[0m"
        }
        throw e
    }
}
```